# NPM Workflow for global modules

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10

I want to globally install dev dependencies like mocha and babel and a few other things as well.  So, I also need to reference to the global modules in the project package.json file.

My idea is to npm init the "npm" directory where the global "node_modules" are and then to install the global modules from there using `npm install --save` so that they are installed globally and the "global" package.json file is udated.  Then, when I want to use one of these modules in a project, I just copy the line from the "global" package.json and paste it into the devDependencies of the project package.json.

My problem is that this was working fine but lately the "global" package.json file is not being updated when I `install --save`.

Why would this stop working?

I'm using Windows 10 and npm v3.8.6

Comment: babel and mocha should still be local to your project

Comment: @naomik what do you mean? Why would I want the same 7k+ files in every project?

Comment: would it make you chance your mind if babel or mocha existed as 1 file instead of 7k ?

Comment: The reason to avoid globally installing these is because each project grows on its own, separate from your other projects. Project A compiles with babel version `U` and tests with mocha version `V`. You might start project B some time later and that uses a newer babel version `X` and mocha version `Y`. There might be minor discrepancies between the two and unless you go update Project A (which you might not have time for), one of the two projects will be broken. Now imagine having 100 projects.

Comment: This is the same for the other similar questions I saw: nobody answers the question, just says don't do it.  So why does npm offer global install if it is completely unusable?

Comment: `npm install -g` is not for project dependencies. It is for utils/bins that you might use to do work but not necessarily a util that your project inherits. One such rare example is `express-generator` which is used to generate some files that get *used* in your project, but the project never depends on `express-generator` itself. Once the files are in your project, you no longer depend on `express-generator` so it doesn't matter which version was used (historically) to generate them. This is a perfect candidate for `install -g`

Comment: *"This is the same for the other similar questions I saw: nobody answers the question, just says don't do it."* – this should be a strong indication to you that you're asking how to do something you shouldn't do... so don't do it, and don't repeat the question.

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't really matter that babel and mocha are 1 file or 7000. You get peace of mind knowing that the project you built using babel-`X` and mocha-`Y` (at the time) will always work because they're always local to your project. And you get the flexibility to upgrade your dependencies on any project without worrying that you will be breaking other projects that depend on babel/mocha/other. It's a matter of practicality and sanity more than anything.

Comment: _.. so don't do it, and don't repeat the question._ So shut up and code? Until your comment above the question was nowhere near landed.

Comment: *"So shut up and code?"* – no, I'm not saying that at all. I'm saying it's not surprising you're having difficulty establishing a workflow to work with global modules in node development; it's because you were never intended to have such a work flow in the first place.

Comment: I'm not trying to be argumentative, so I'm sorry if you're misinterpreting me. You don't have to take advice from me if you don't want to. I was only trying to help you avoid a nightmare.

Comment: anyway you advice was very helpful so I think it was worthwhile _"repeating the question"_.  Turns out my IDE is very concerned if it is one file or 7K coz it want's to index them all the time and was grinding to a halt.  I guess I wasn't the only one with this problem since the latest version of Webstorm has `node_modules` permanently excluded from indexing and this fixes the sluggish behaviour...

Comment: Yep, it's extremely common to ignore vendor files in your ide. This makes it easier to search/navigate your own code. Many people will exclude binaries or other compiled files such as any images or their `build` directory as well.